# How to concatenate table name with variable within for loop in sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to write a one time (as in never to be run again) script to collect information about usage of certain features of our product. Here is a simplified script that I have right now:

```sql
begin
  for db in (select owner from dba_tables where table_name='feature_table') loop
    begin
      for info in (select * from db.owner.feature_table where something='important') loop
        begin
          dbms_output.put_line(db.owner||' , '||info.type||' , '||info.source);
        end;
      end loop;
    end;
  end loop;
end;
```

I get an error in the inner loop at "db.owner.feature_table". I also tried passing it as concatenated string, but to no avail. What do I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Why not just query the applicable tables and output the results?

Comment: I presume you mean skipping the first loop. The reason I need it because it will end up with few thousand records. So it needs to loop over few thousand times on average 10 records. It would be a lot of manual labor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you have is that the result of:

```
for db in (select owner from dba_tables where table_name='feature_table') loop
```

is an in memory record consisting of a single field, owner. It is not a database table therefor your nested FOR..LOOP cannot query it. `db.owner.feature_table` refers to the in-memory record and feature_table is not a property of db.owner.

An option to achieve what you are attempting would be to use dynamic SQL (http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm) and specifically [this section](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/dynamic.htm#i13057) that will allow you to have a dynamic nested FOR..LOOP.

To be honest though for a one off script it may be not be worth the effort.

Comment: Thank you! I used concatenation instead of bind variables (couldn't get them to substitute) but it works now.